# Merge multiple rows in a single

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need merge multiple rows in a single row with data concatenated on the columns.

This three lines are result is from my query with **INNER JOIN**

```
Name  | SC     | Type
----------------------
name1 | 121212 | type1
name2 | 123456 | null
name3 | null   | type1
```

I want display result like this:

```
Name  | SC     | Type
----------------------
name1; 121212; type1;
name2; 123456; ;
name3; ;       type1;
```

It's a single row, each column with data concatenated with `;` and a `\n` in the end of each data.

The final query need run in SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: Oracle has ANSI SQL's `||` (and also `CONCAT( string1, string2 )`.) SQL Server has `+` and also `CONCAT()`.)

Answer (score 3):

I honestly doubt you can use the same query in both oracle and SQL-Server since they both have different functions when it comes to dealing with null values.

For Oracle:

```
SELECT NVL(Name,'') || ';' as name,
       NVL(SC,'') || ';' as SC,
       NVL(type,'') || ';' as type
FROM (YourQueryHere)
```

For SQL-Server

```
SELECT isnull(Name,'') + ';' as name,
       isnull(SC,'') + ';' as SC,
       isnull(type,'') + ';' as type
FROM (YourQueryHere)
```

Note that as @jarlh said, in concatenating side you can use concat(value,value2) which should work both on SQL-Server and Oracle, depending on your version.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply concatenate the fields:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(Name,'') + ';' as Name, 
        ISNULL(SC, '') + ';' as SC, 
        ISNULL(Type, '') + ';' as Type
FROM 
(
    -- whatever is your query goes here...
);
```

Comment: Does Oracle support `+` for concatenation?

Comment: Result is a single column in this example. I need three columns, each with the data concatenated.

Comment: @jarlh, this is SQL Server syntax. You can substitute `||` for `+` and `NVL` for `ISNULL` for Oracle.

Comment: If `SC` is numeric, then you should add `CAST(SC as nvarchar(10))`